# Is there a way I can shorten this if statment?

Tags: c, if-statement, char, logical-operators

I have this really large if statement and it does not look pleasing to the eye as well as not being as efficient as possible.

I'm making a program that (depending on the users input) runs a certain block of code, for example if the user inputs `'a'` the program runs a code that adds something to a file etc. By the way this is in a do-while statement(I don't know if this is relevant though).

```
else if(ansr != 'a' && ansr != 'A' && ansr != 'r' && ansr != 'R' && ansr != 's' && ansr != 'S' && ansr != 'e' && ansr != 'E')
{
    printf("Invalid input!\n");
}
```

As you can see this is a really long if statement and I would like it to be shorter. Thank you

Comment: It's customary to ask about one language at a time. C or C++?

Comment: c, I thought they were pretty close enough. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Since this is `else if` I assume you are handling those different characters in `if`,`else if` statements above? Why wouldn't a simple `else` be used catch the invalid input that falls through?

Comment: when I use `else` it prints `Invalid Input` no matter what.

Comment: Can you post the full `if`,`else if` logic you're using?

Comment: @Romen Sorry I don't think I can as it is a very long however it is pretty much formatted as follows: `else if(ansr == 'S' || ansr == 's')`,  `S` and `s` being the example.

Comment: @BelalKassem, So you have something like `if (ansr == 'A' || ansr == 'a')` and then a bunch of `else if ....` lines afterwards for each other input option? And you're saying that using `else` at the very end will always cause the `else` case to execute? Can you at least update your question with the full `if`,`else if` logic and remove the code inside?

Comment: Okay, I updated my code and made it overall more efficient by using `ansr = tolower(ansr);` in the very begging of my code and now i'm experimenting with all the options you guys gave me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um, what an example, whatever.

Why don't you use `strchr`? `strchr` returns the pointer to a character in a string (if found), NULL otherwise.

```c
else if (strchr("aArRsSeE", ansr) == NULL)
{
    printf("Invalid input!\n");
}
```

Comment: Such an unfortunate string.

Comment: would have been funnier with some more reordering.

Comment: Can you please explain what does `strchr` do and how it works? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with:

```
switch(tolower(ansr)) {
case 'a':
case 'r':
case 's':
case 'e':
    do_stuff();
    break;
/* other cases here */
}
```

Or you can use more library functions such as:

```
if (strchr("ares", tolower(ansr)) {
    do_stuff();
}
```

[`strchr`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) function is searching for a given character in the given string and returns `NULL` if it is not there (or pointer to first occurrence of it, but it is not the use-case which we are interested in here)

- This is assuming `ansr` is in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`. Otherwise the behavior of `tolower` is undefined.

Comment: Use `tolower((unsigned char)ansr)`, otherwise you can easily get UB.

Comment: Even if it's `char`, you get UB if it's negative (and `!= EOF`).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it is a char, and can you please explain what does `strchr` do?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, I would personally use a [switch statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm). It is easy to use and easy to read. Another thing which would make your code slightly more readable is using [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/).
Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    char inp = 'i';
    char ansr = toupper(inp);
    switch(ansr) {
        case 'A' :
            // Do something
            break;
        case 'R' :
            // Do something
            break;
        case 'S' :
            // Do something
            break;
        case 'E' :
            // Do something
            break;
        default :
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if the case of the `ansr` is important, converting to lowercase before the if statement would half the amount of checks needed.

Comment: Can you please explain how you do that?

Comment: The prototype for `tolower()` is `int tolower(int c);` so to be sure to avoid undefined behavior you have to pass `tolower()` an **unsigned** `char` value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to write an `else if` case to catch input characters that you *do not* support. The `else` case is perfect for that kind of situation:

```
...
char input;
//get your input
if (input == 'A' || input == 'a')
    DoA();
else if (input == 'R' || input == 'r')
    DoR();
else if (input == 'S' || input == 's')
    DoS();
else if (input == 'E' || input == 'e')
    DoE();
else
    DoInvalidInput();
```

Or if you use `tolower()` you can put that in a `switch` statement:

```
char lowerChar = tolower((unsigned char)input);
switch (lowerChar)
{
    case 'a': DoA(); break;
    case 'r': DoR(); break;
    case 's': DoS(); break;
    case 'e': DoE(); break;
    default: DoInvalidInput(); break;
}
```